# Graphing Differential Vector Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vectors, graphing-functions

My linear algebra book is discussing differential vector equations, and they give the example function $x(t) = (-3/70)\begin{bmatrix}-5\\2\end{bmatrix}e^{6t} + (188/70)\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}e^{-t}$. They then graph the function as follows: [image: graph]
The thing is, when I plug numbers in for $t$, and graph by hand, I only get one line -- not all these lines as they show on this graph and similar graphs. So I'm confused on what they're doing here. Can somebody explain to me how to properly graph these equations? Thank you.

Comment: This are solutions of the differential for various initial conditions.

Comment: @amd would you mind explaining to me what that means? I am fairly new to differential equations.